# CakePHP 3: Scope in Tree behavior

Tags: tree, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I thought I'd use the *tree behavior* for my menus as the manual suggests but I've become increasingly confused.

I would like to be able to retrieve menu data based on the current controller which i can get from the request object.

I thought if i had that i could set the scope for the tree behavior on the fly using:

```php
$this->behaviors()->Tree->config('scope', ['country_name' => 'France']);
```

I thought from there i could just select all nodes with something like:

```php
$this->MyModel->find('all')
```

But that returns everything.

I read in the manual that scope restricts the scope of all operations so that's an area of confusion.

I also tried

```php
$this->MyModel->find('threaded')
```

but that returns everything.

It's good that it returns the whole tree as it should because it shows that I've done at least part of it right.

The really weird part is this:

```php
$this->MyModel->find('children', ['for' => 1]);
```

It returns exactly what i would expect as long as i don't set the scope. If i set the scope the the tree whose id is 1 i get an empty array.

So to summarize. Here's the code I'm using in a view cell.

```php
$this->loadModel('MyModel');

$this->MyModel->behaviors()->Tree->config('scope', ['title' => 'MyTreeTitle']);

$this->MyModel->find('threaded')->toArray();
```

And as i said before it returns the two separate trees in my table rather than just the one whose title matches the defined scope.

Also, I've manually checked the lft and rght values to make sure they are correct and they seem to be.

Would really appreciate some help on this one as I am monumentally confused.

**EDIT**

I've done a bit more fiddling and part of the above is wrong.

I output the result of

```php
$this->MyModel->find('children', ['for' => 1]);
```

as a treelist and with the scope set it actually just returns the node i want to find the children for. I expected scope to return a single node and children based on a unique value. After re-reading the manual several times it has now sunk in that it returns ONLY rows that contain the scope value. Not sure how that is useful in a tree data context unless you have a hierarchy of countries (in the case of the manual) rather than something like countries->cities->landmarks.

Can anyone tell me if this is intended behavior?

I should also mention that I'm using Postgresql. Maybe that's a factor.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Items scoped..

Something like

```
$table= \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry::get('Plugin.Table');
$table->behaviors()->Tree->config('scope', ['Table.scope' => $scope]);
/* where scope is the country_name or title in your case */
$row = $table->newEntity();
$row = $table->patchEntity($row, ['your_row_column'=>'row_column_data'])
$table->save($row)
```

To retrieve the items just do

```
        $this->Table->find('children', [
            'contain'=>'SomethingRelated', 
            'for' => $table_row_id 
        ])->find('threaded')->toArray()
```

[#cakephprullz](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#scoping-and-multi-trees)